# Preserve database relationships

Tags: 7, nodes, upgrading

We're in the process of figuring out quite how much work upgrading to Drupal 7 is going to be. The thing that is really worrying me, is that we currently have our main content as Nodes:

- Equipment
- Person
- Company
- Address
- Contract
- Timesheet

Now, these are linked together using join tables (timesheet for person, address for company, etc) using the node ids, obviously.

Anyway, the possibility of exporting all of this information somehow is quite frankly impossible. The only way we can possibly do it is to be able to import Nodes into the new format and preserve the current Node IDs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you will always want to preserve node IDs on migration, for many reasons. If these join tables are maintained by custom modules of your own, then migration of the data is not going to be so much an issue as updating the modules themselves. You can continue to use custom DB tables in D7 but you will need to change code to reflect new APIs.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading is a pain in the ass you will need to migrate things which will not work upon migration, you will have to reset options in views as views will not recognize migrated content. I've been doing this for 2 month I still dont know how to migrate this drupal 6 to drupal 7